# cloud-ml predict sometimes fails providing the same input

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm using Google cloud machine learning to get prediction on an image.

I have created a model and a version in cloud-ml with my training data, but when I try to get a prediction with `gcloud beta ml predict` sometimes cloud-ml gives me the correct results, while some other times using the same command and the same files I encounter a server error 502, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m19jm.jpg).

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121254/cloud-machine-learning-predict) and I know that predict is actually an alpha feature and sometimes it gives problems. Can it be my case?

If so, is there alternative? Or, will there be a new release in the near future?

Comment: We are continuously working to improve the reliability of the service. How far apart from each other did you issue each call? Do you have a sense for how "big" your model is (both in disk and how much RAM it uses while loaded in memory and processing data)?

Comment: I don't know exactly how big is my model. (I think it is quite small). When I export data in cloud-ml, the dimension of export.meta file is 80MB more or less.

Comment: What about the checkpoint files, how big are those? How many instances are you sending to the service in a single response (just 1, or multiple)? How big is the payload?

Comment: I don't have any checkpoint files, but I save only the final results in two files: export.meta and export (Using command: saver.save(sess, os.path.join(output_directory,'export'))), with dimension 80-90MB the first and some KB the second. Now I'm sending only one instance to the service. Instance is about 4MB as dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the online prediction feature is now in Beta.

I'd suggest trying your scenario to see if you can get past the failed requests on startup.

In particular, please ensure the request to deploy a model version is complete before issuing requests.